# "Can't write to connection" error when checkout local tortoiseSVN repo (svn://localhost)

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

My laptop runs Windows 10 Pro.

I'm using Eclipse 4.16 (2020-06) with Subclipse plugin installed.

I have a TortoiseSVN client running on my localhost, and I can access it via svn://localhost using Repository Browser.

[image]

I want to checkout the repo directly from Eclipse, but I always get the error

> `Cannot checkout. An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.`
>
> `svn: Can't write to connection: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.`

Same thing happens when I try to create a new repo from existing project on Eclipse.

Things work well when I try with online SVN repo.

[image]

***Update:*** I can open cmd and run command `svn checkout svn://localhost/project` and it successfully checkout my project. But when I try using the TortoiseSVN checkout from Right click menu, I also get the same error.

[image]
[image]
What is wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps Subclipse doesn't support the `svn` protocol. I don't know whether it does—they don't even use the word "protocol" in their documentation

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's something wrong with my TortoiseSVN v.1.14. Solved the issue by reinstalling TortoiseSVN version 1.9.